# Flurry crashing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, flurry

1. Create a single view application.
2. In `AppDelegate.m`, put this method:

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
       // Override point for customization after application launch.
       [Flurry startSession:@"YOUR_TEST_FLURRY_APPID"];
       NSString* event = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"TEST_EVENT"];
       [Flurry logEvent:event];
       return YES;
   }
   ```
3. Include Flurry SDK in your project.
4. Enjoy crash on any iPhone :)

Can somebody know, why?

-- UPDATE --

- You can find full project here: https://github.com/maltsevda/FlurryCrash
- Crash log here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwv2y5Duq2tyMFNYZmRhUG0yUzg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: add your crash log here for understand your issue.

Comment: Have you replaced the text @"YOUR_TEST_FLURRY_APPID" with your flurry APPID?

Comment: Can you please download latest SDK of Flurry and Test in Demo app of Flurry also ? We have integrated before few days and working properly.

Comment: Added crash log and full test project. With newest flurry SDK and valid APP code.

Comment: I fixed some grammar issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is a legitimate crash on Flurry 6.3.0. It was caused by calling logEvent too quickly after the startSession.

We have fixed this in 6.4.0 which was released this month. Please give that version of the SDK a try.

Disclaimer: I work at Flurry.